# MSYS, Windows и имена

Tags: msys2

Вкратце: Можно ли сменить имя пользователя в msys принудительно?
Полностью: Отладчики (которыми я пользуюсь) не работают корректно, если в пути до проекта встречается кириллица. Значительная часть проектов лежит в .../msys64/home/ЮзернеймКириллицей/work
На сколько мне известно, MSYS выбирает имя пользователя исходя из имени пользователя в винде. Поэтому я поменял его через панель управления->смена имени пользователя, перезагрузился и удалил каталог home.
При запуске MSYS Он создал home заново, но имя папка внутри все еще была написана кириллицей. То ли windows где-то еще хранит старое имя пользователя, и MSYS берет его оттуда, то ли лыжи не едут
Что посоветуете в таком случае?

Comment: _то ли windows где-то еще хранит старое имя пользователя_ наверняка в регистре где-то. Вообще переименование пользователя в windows весьма не тривиальная задача, проще создать нового пользователя и пользоваться им, либо попробовать что-то сделать с символическими ссылками

Comment: на счёт смены имени через панель управления не уверен, когда было нужно получилось нормально сменить только через wmic useraccount where name="OldName" call rename "NewName"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я попробовал еще раз просмотреть регистр по совету Grundy,  к моему удивлению там было много записей с моим кириллическим именем, хотя я их до этого чистил, но, в основном, это были пути к папкам, и ничего, на что мог бы опираться MSYS, я не нашел. Тогда я начал играться с wmic useraccount where name="OldName" call rename "NewName". Со второй попытки добился код возврата 0 (не помню, что, но что-то я сделал). После перезагрузки msys создал новую папку и теперь пишет мой ник латинскими буквами (папка тоже теперь латиницей)
**Итого, чтобы решить проблему:**

1. Открываем CMD от имени администратора (в обычном режиме не пробовал)
2. Вводим
   wmic useraccount where name="OldName" call rename "NewName"
   По-моему, в этом виде оно и сработало. Естесственно, OldName меняем на свое имя кириллицей (старое имя), NewName - латиницей (на то оно и новое)
3. Убеждаемся, что код возврата 0 (иначе - экспериментируем и гуглим)
4. Перезагружаем комп (!!!)
5. Запускаем MSYS
6. Если он начал создавать новые папочки, все путем, можно радоваться. Иначе - идем на шаг 2 и не пропускаем шаг 3.
   P.S. Спасибо [Isaev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/20392/isaev) и [Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy) за команду wmic и советы.